# Correlation of non-uniform time-series data?

Tags: time-series, correlation

I have two datasets of time-series data, each with arbitrary, non-linear sampling intervals. I'm planning to analyze them using either Pearson or Spearman correlation (determined by the detection of outliers using the 3-sigma rule) but I believe that the correlation between times at which each sample was taken may be relevant.

Does anyone know of a good algorithm to correlate this type of time-series data, taking into account sample time if it's relevant? Pseudo-code is particularly welcome...

Comment: A better way to characterize this data is "irregular", rather than non-uniform. My apologies for any confusion :)